# Continuous function that has the same sign of a discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. What are the sufficient and necessary condition on $f$ to guarantee the existence of continuous function $g$ such that $f(x)>0\iff g(x)>0$?

I am guessing that the following two conditions are equivalent:

1. $\{x:f(x)>0\}$ is an open set
2. $g$ exists

I don't know how to find a (preferably) existential proof.

Comment: I think you don't have to assume that $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: Consider the set $A$ where $f \leq 0$. Take as $g(x)$ the distance of $x$ to this set.

Comment: The set where $g>0$ must be open.

Comment: @copper.hat If $g$ is continuous then I guess $g>0$ is open?

Comment: @dodo Yes. ${}{}$

Comment: @PhoemueX Is it possible to have an existential proof without constructing a specific function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $g(x):=\inf \{\delta \ge 0 : \exists y \in \mathbb{R}^2,f(y)\le 0,\|x-y\|<\delta\}$. Clearly, $g$ is continuous since it has Lipschitz constant $\le 1$, and if $\{x:f(x)>0\}$ is open, then $g(x)>0$ for all $x$ such that $f(x)>0$.

Conversely, suppose $g$ exists, then since $g$ is continuous, the preimage $g^{-1}((0,\infty))=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2:f(x)>0\}$ is open.